# DevExpress GridView SQL: how to add new data to the drawn table without adding a column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I am pulling data from a SQL Server database without adding any columns on the C# ASP.NET DevExpress GridView aspx side. How can I update this data I captured or add new data to the table?

In my project, the system administrator adds his own module. When adding this module, my code creates a table in my SQL Server database according to the module name. After creating the module, it adds columns one by one. These added columns are added as columns to the table in the SQL Server database. I am dynamically pulling this table added on the portal to the gridview, and I want to add new records to this table via the gridview and edit existing records.

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

SqlCommand cmdara = new SqlCommand("select * from " + tabloadi + " where TARIH BETWEEN @baslangic AND @bitis", db_baglanti);

cmdara.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baslangic", dateBasla.Value);
cmdara.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bitis", dateBitis.Value);

SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdara);
adap.Fill(tbl);

gridModul.DataSource = tbl;
gridModul.DataBind();
```

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridModul" runat="server" KeyFieldName="id" ClientInstanceName="gridModul" 
        Theme="Office365" OnCustomColumnDisplayText="gridModul_CustomColumnDisplayText" OnDataBound="gridModul_DataBound" >
        <ClientSideEvents RowDblClick="function(s,e) { s.StartEditRow(e.visibleIndex); }" /> 
                    <SettingsEditing Mode="PopupEditForm">
                    </SettingsEditing>
                    <Settings ShowHeaderFilterBlankItems="False" ShowHeaderFilterButton="True" />
                    <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="true" AllowSelectByRowClick="true" AllowEllipsisInText="true" AllowDragDrop="false" />
        <SettingsPopup>
            <EditForm HorizontalAlign="Center">
            </EditForm>
        </SettingsPopup>
        <SettingsSearchPanel CustomEditorID="SearchButtonEdit" />
        <SettingsPager PageSize="15" EnableAdaptivity="true">
            <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true"></PageSizeItemSettings>
        </SettingsPager>
        <SettingsExport EnableClientSideExportAPI="true" ExportSelectedRowsOnly="true" />
         <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: Can you please change all of your question to english?

Comment: Also translate the title, please.

Answer (score 0):

The display is simple, you can just add an AutoGenerateColumns=true to the markup and it will display whatever you send to it.
The insert/update will require you to iterate through the columns and map to a dynamic SQL INSERT/UPDATE command with your column list mapping the values from the insert/update you are attempting.
You will need to assign these events in the markup and handle the above process there in the codebehind.

OnRowUpdating="gridModul_RowUpdating"
OnRowInserting="gridModul_RowInserting"

In codebehind:

```
OrderedDictionary odNew = e.NewValues; 
foreach (DictionaryEntry formParam in odNew)
{
 // build your dynamic SQL with formParam.Value 
 // matching formParam.Key to your column name;
}
```

Comment: Hello,

I know I will do it behind the code, but how will I pull the columns visible in the table while inserting? I would like you to share an example code.

Comment: In the _RowInserting Event, for example, you will have an OrderedDictionary of e.NewValues: 

                //accept new values from edit form in event NewValues OrderedDictionary format, build SQL string, call update, refresh grid.
                OrderedDictionary odNew = e.NewValues;

You will need to include:
using System.Collections.Specialized;

For the OrderedDictionary Class. 

In the _RowUpdating method you will have access to the OldValues and NewValues OrderedDictionary entries.  The Key will be your field names.

Comment: Can you answer with sample code?